# Fastest way in python for finding object with certain attribute value from list?

Tags: python, list, class, uniqueidentifier, loops

What would be the fastest and/or easiest (speed preferred) way to find an object, that has certain value on certain attribute, from a list of objects. I got a list of classes, which I am looping through, and I also got a list of objects, and I need to see if the object is an instance of the currently being-looped class. Here's what I've been using so far, but it's a pain in the ass for speed purposes.

```
for cSoldier in soldierlist:
    exists = False
    for soldier in user.soldiers:
        if cSoldier.id == soldier.id:
            exists = True
            break
    if not exists:
        user.soldiers.append(cSoldier())
```

`soldierlist` holds in all the different soldier classes, for example class Sniper, class Knight, etc.

`user.soldiers` is used for storing one instance of each soldier type for every user of this game

`id` each soldier class has it's unique classid, and it's also being given to each instance of that class, to recognize the instance's type

Comment: Use a dictionary and map ids to their respective soldiers. Once you construct the dictionary, it's `O(1)` lookup time instead of `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which avoids constantly rescanning the list

```
current_ids = set(soldier.id for soldier in user.soldiers)
for soldier_class in soldierlist:
    if soldier_class.id not in current_ids:
         user.soldiers.append( soldier_class() )
```

By storing all the ids in set, looking them up can be done much faster then just rescanning through the list.

Answer (score 3):

If you define `__hash__` in your soldier class to return the soldier `id` and define `__eq__` to test for `id` equality, you could try something like this:

```
user.soldiers = list(set(user.soldiers + soldierlist))
```

---

So, somewhere in your soldier class:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return self.id

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.id == other.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late, and now maybe useless, but i've had the same issue. So, for the record. 
My fix was to make a object list and a object index:

```
class Soldier:

soldiers = []
soldier_list = []

s_data = {"name":"jim", "id":"foo","type":"bar"}

name = soldier.get("name")
if name not in soldier_list:
    soldiers.append(Soldier(**s_data)) #creates a object with s_data attribs
    soldier_list.append(name)
```